# How can I declare/use static members in Moose?

Tags: perl, oop, moose

I am using Moose objects, but I need to declare static members for things that will be done just once and are not object related.

Do you have any ideas or examples?

Thanks

Dotan.

Comment: Just use a plain package variable like you would in vanilla Perl.

Comment: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=897346

Answer (score 6):

You can use [MooseX::ClassAttribute](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX%3a%3aClassAttribute):

```
package SomeClass;
use Moose;
use MooseX::ClassAttribute;

class_has 'static_member' => ( is => 'rw' );
```

The member is accesses using `SomeClass->static_member`.

Answer (score 2):

I tried playing around with MooseX::ClassAttribute as bvr suggested, but I ended up just setting them as read-only members with a default:

```
has 'static_thing' => ( is => 'ro', init_arg => undef, default => 42 );
```

It seems simpler.

Comment: For anything that doesn't consume a lot of memory, or where it is okay to have multiple copies of the same thing, this is fine -- but sometimes you need just one copy of the same thing (say a database handle) to be shared across all objects, which is where a class attribute can be of use.

Comment: I used that on one or two places so far, typically for something that needs to be shared among class members (as Ether said).

Comment: Also note that you'd need an instance to access the non-static attribute. Getting an instance is not always convenient.

Answer (score 2):

under all the cervine-ness there is still Plain Old Perl

so just set a variable in the class .pm file

```
package SomeClass;
use Moose;

my $instance_counter = 0;

around BUILDARGS => sub {
    $instance_counter += 1;
}

. . .
```